# Primal-dual subgradient method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In [these notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgrad_method_notes.pdf), an extension of the subgradient method is presented in Section 8 (page 30). The method is described so quickly and neither convergence analysis (compared to classical subgradient for example) nor related references are discussed.

I would like to know more about these and googled but did not find anything.

I saw in the References a paper of Nesterov titled "[Primal-dual subgradient methods for convex problems](http://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/s12/GS-Nesterov%20Primal-dual.pdf)", however, this does not seem to be the same method.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: That's not a paper; that's notes from a class. And it looks like [BPV97] is the reference they rely upon. (See the top of page 31.)

Comment: @MichaelGrant: oh yes, I abused the word "paper", thanks for pointing that out.
I had read (quickly) [BPV97] before asking and thought that the reference was for0 the definition (or things related to) the Uzawa iteration only. But you might be right, I will read that paper more in depth to see.

Comment: HI, did you find any useful reference for the primal-dual subgradient method in these lecture notes? Based on my simulations, it seems that dual variables don't converge. Thanks.

Comment: It might be a little delayed answer, but you might be interested in the following paper by Nedic and Ozdaglar "Subgradient Methods for Saddle-Point Problems".